# Working with Term Store with same terms across multiple departments

Tags: term-store, term-set

I'm working with a company that has several departments. Two or more of these departments do the same type of document like a "Lease". The issue is that these departments also do several other documents that do not cross departments and I'm trying to avoid creating one long list they have to search through to get to the "Lease". I tried using the "Reuse Term" to put the "Lease" term in the different term sets but you can only do this one time.  You can put the same term in different term sets but it's not the same term (same name but different GUID).  It seems like this would be a common issue but I can't seem to find a simple answer to the question other than just creating one super long list.   Any suggestions?